# Qucikblox : How to add user in friend list?

Tags: ios, quickblox

I am able to load user list by `[QBUsers usersWithPagedRequest:request delegate:self];` But it lists all the users that are available in my account. I want to load only friend list for the user.

I want to know that how can I load only list of friends ? Is **QuickBlox** provides such mechanism  or we need to use own server to maintain the flow ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store friends in contact list.

```
[QBChat instance].contactList
```

(http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Contact_list)

Or you can create custom object for each user, set one field - users' ID array and update it when add or delete new friend.

Comment: Thanks for reply.. which way is preferable/flexible/Best ?

Comment: Not at all. If you use QB chat module, I think [QBChat instance].contactList more easy.  But more flexible is creating CO bacause in future you can add some fields like a phone number (In this case CO is extension for user profile).